# How to fix image loading time with my image slider?

Tags: html, css

I have an image slider in the website I'm currently working on. It works fine in the beginning when you open the webpage and slides through all the images, but when it goes back to show the first image which is image.png in the rotation of the image slider, it takes time to load it. When the first image comes back into the view again, a white background comes up first because I'm guessing it is loading all the images again into the slider. How do I fix this cause it is only 4 images i'm using in the slider now.

html

```
    <div id="slider">
        <figure>

                <img src="image.png"></img>
                <img src="sample.png"></img>
                <img src="sample1.png"></img>
                <img src="sample2.png"></img>
        </figure>
    </div>
```

css code which I got from a tutorial

```
  @keyframes slidy {
  0% { left: 0%; }
  20% { left: 0%; }
  25% { left: -100%; }
  45% { left: -100%; }
  50% { left: -200%; }
  70% { left: -200%; }
  75% { left: -300%; }
  95% { left: -300%; }
  100% { left: -400%; }
  }


  div#slider { overflow: hidden; }
  div#slider figure img { width: 20%; float: left; }
  div#slider figure { 
  position: relative;
  width: 500%;
  margin: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 0;
  animation: 40s slidy infinite; 
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That white area you see is the space where there is no image at `left: -400%`.

There are at least two ways to fix this, depending on the behavior you want.

### Option 1 - Always scroll to the left

If you always want the images to slide to the left, even when going from the last image back to the first image, then eliminate the white space by repeating the first image in your HTML as the fifth image:

```
<div id="slider">
    <figure>
        <img src="image.png"></img>
        <img src="sample.png"></img>
        <img src="sample1.png"></img>
        <img src="sample2.png"></img>
        <img src="image.png"></img>
    </figure>
</div>
```

There is no animation between the fifth image and the first image, so this will work just fine.

### Option 2 - Scroll to the right to return to the first image

You have defined a keyframe at 100% to scroll to `left: -400%` where there is no image, just whitespace.  Then, it immediately goes to the keyframe at 0% with `left: 0%`.  If, instead of scrolling left into whitespace, you want it to scroll to the right, back to the first image, just remove the keyframe at 100%:

```
@keyframes slidy {
     0% { left: 0%; }
    20% { left: 0%; }
    25% { left: -100%; }
    45% { left: -100%; }
    50% { left: -200%; }
    70% { left: -200%; }
    75% { left: -300%; }
    95% { left: -300%; }
}
```

This way, when the animation is between 95% and 0%, it will scroll to the right, from `left: -300%` to `left: 0%`.